# Equivalence between two systems of vector equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, vector-analysis

I need to solve the system

$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{u} = \nabla p \\ 
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$$

in a subdomain of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with mixed boundary conditions, where $\mathbf{u}$ is vector field and p is a scalar field.
Taking the divergence of the first equation,
using the definition of vector Laplacian
$\nabla^2 \mathbf{u} = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{u})$, the second equation and the identity $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{v}) = 0$, we have
$$ \nabla \cdot (\nabla^2 \mathbf{u}) = 0 = \nabla \cdot \nabla p = \nabla^2 p$$

I would like to know if the system
$$ \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} = \nabla p  \\ \nabla^2 p = 0
$$

which was derived using $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$, is equivalent to the first one.

It has the advantage of allowing to solve first for $p$ and then for $\mathbf{u}$, in a decoupled fashion. Unfortunately, according to my numerical experiments and save numerical problems, they are not equivalent, but I don't see why the solution for the second is not a solution for the first one.

Comment: By "numerically not equivalent", do you mean you are solving each system with the same boundary data and getting different answers?

Comment: No, I am not solving the first system. However, when I solve the second one, I get as an answer a field $\mathbf{u}$ that doesn't verify $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$.

Comment: Are you enforcing appropriate boundary data on $u$?

Comment: I am enforcing $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ on walls and null normal derivative at inlet and outlet.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm leaning toward numerical issue since typically (to the best of my knowledge) the first system is actually solved by solving the second; i.e., incompressibility is enforced by solving for pressure in the fashion you've done.

Comment: Any number of issues could be arising. Can you start with a very simple set up and find an analytic solution by hand so you _know_ what your numerical solution should look like?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb, it works perfectly for a simple set up.

Comment: Physically, the boundary is divided in two subdomains, $I$ and $W$. On $I$, $p$ is known. On $W$, $u$ is known. What are appropriate boundary conditions for $u$ on $I$ and $p$ on $W$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "equivalent" but here is a possible issue:

You have shown $\nabla \cdot u=0 $ $\Rightarrow$ $\nabla^2p=0$, which is correct according to your system. However, the converse does not necessarily hold:

$\nabla^2 p=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\nabla \cdot (\nabla^2 u) = 0$ which does not necessarily entail that $\nabla \cdot u=0$. In particular, any $u$ satisfying Laplace's equation satisfies this. So the equations $\nabla \cdot u=0$ and $\nabla^2 p=0$ are not "equivalent."

Comment: What do you mean by "Laplace's equation"?

Comment: Laplace's equation is $\nabla^2 u =0$

Comment: In the system under consideration $\nabla^2 u = \nabla p$, so a $u$ that satisfies Laplace's equation is not a solution for the system.

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is one may not replace the equation $\nabla \cdot u=0$ with $\nabla^2 p=0$ since there is no biconditional between these statements. Mentioning Laplace's equation was meant to emphasize the fact that $u$ may satisfy $\nabla \cdot (\nabla^2u)=0$ but not $\nabla \cdot u=0$, and you need the latter to be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

We're kind of going back and forth a lot, so I'll move it to an answer.

Typically when we want to solve unforced incompressible Stokes flow (I assume this is your task at hand?), to enforce incompressibility, we must solve the Poisson equation for pressure $p$ (your last equation), and use this result to plug in to the momentum balance (the first equation).

Of course, even being able to solve any of these depend on the well-posedness of the corresponding equation, and for the Poisson equation that means a well-defined boundary data. "Not knowing" your pressure along the walls means you need to make an ansatz about what happens here: I might suggest a linear interpolation between the inlet pressure and outlet pressure (choosing an appropriate ansatz is itself a complex issue). Whatever you do, you need boundary data for $p$ along the entire boundary in order to make the problem well-defined and to adequately solve the Poisson equation. Only *then* can you plug it in to the momentum balance to get your incompressible Stokes flow.

Comment: My ansatz for p on the walls is null normal derivative, which is consistent with the no penetration condition.

Comment: Those conditions make sense. What are your boundary conditions for $u$?

Comment: for u, zero at the walls and and null normal derivative at the inlet and outlet.